# How to install php_gmp in MacOS catalina, Xampp VM and php7.3

Tags: php, xampp, gmp

I am using Web Push library to send push notification but getting error -

> Warning: [WebPush] gmp extension is not loaded but is required for sending push notifications with payload or for VAPID authentication

i have enabled `extension:php_gmp` in **php.ini** but still same issue is there.
i am new to MacOS environment and so have no clue,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem. The issue was with modifying the wrong file in my case.

[List of files with .ini extension in D:\xampp\php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4XhCL.png)

In the attached image above, the files in the red rectangle is what I was initially changing but the one that should be modified is the file in the green rectangle. After uncommenting the gmp extension I no longer got the error.

[Location of the specific .ini file to modify](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IdGEb.png)

You can find the specific php.ini file in the second image directly above.